# AWS SnapStart For Java Lambda Using AWS CDK

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to orchestrate Lambda's using the Java 11 (or 17) AWS CDK. Lambda has serious issues with JVM compilation and cold starts, so I have been looking into using the newer SnapStart feature offered by AWS. The CDK pushes the CloudFormation stack with SnapStart components included, a new version of the Lambda, and an Alias for the version. These are all necessary requirements for SnapStart.

**CDK Lambda Creation w/ SnapStart Config & Alias**

```
       //Lambda Function
        String lambdaHandlerName = "com.handlers.lambdaHandler::handleRequest";
        IRole role5 = Role.fromRoleName(this, "Lambda", "LambdaRole");

        Function lambdaFunction = new Function(this, "lambdaFunction", getLambdaFunctionProps(lambdaEnvMap, lambdaHandlerName, role5, "lambdaHandler"));
        dynamoTable.grantReadData(lambdaFunction);

        //SnapStart Config
        lambdaFunction.getCurrentVersion().addAlias("snap", AliasOptions.builder()
                .description("Alias version for snap resources")
                .build());
        CfnFunction lambdaCfnFunction = (CfnFunction) lambdaCfnFunction.getNode().getDefaultChild();
        lambdaCfnFunction.setSnapStart(CfnFunction.SnapStartProperty.builder()
                .applyOn("PublishedVersions")
                .build());
```

Within the AWS Console itself, it appears SnapStart is enabled for the base function set to "PublishedVersions".

[SnapStart enabled on base function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1r0t.png)

And when I look at my most recently published version, I find that it too has SnapStart enabled.

[SnapStart enabled on Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU1Ao.png)

But when I invoke my Lambda function through API Gateway (which is configured to the correct version of Lambda), SnapStart does not seem to be working for the function and my cold start times are still ~2s.

I have also tried implementing runtime hooks, suggested by AWS for SnapStart to the Lambda function handler itself:

**Handler Runtime Hooks for SnapStart**

```
   public GetAllQuotesHandler() {
        Core.getGlobalContext().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event, Context context) {
      ...
    }

    
    @Override
    public void beforeCheckpoint(org.crac.Context<? extends Resource> context) throws Exception {
        this.dynamoDb.close();
        System.out.println("Before");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterRestore(org.crac.Context<? extends Resource> context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After");
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my configuration, any advice?

I am expecting AWS Lambda to engage SnapStart and invoke my Lambda function without cold starts.

Comment: Have you managed to improve it?

Comment: No, SnapStart is for sure enabled and I am still facing 2s-3s cold start times for the function.